# Troubleshoot web server

Tags: apache-http-server, firewall

I realize that this question maybe don't have a simple answer, but I am really stuck and out of ideas.

I have set up an Apache server. Between me and the server there are two firewalls. The problem is that I can access the server via the internal IP, but not external. However, the external works when I'm on the actual server. The reason I'm setting up this server is that it should replace an old. I have copied all rules I could find in the firewall so that they should be identical, but I'm really out of ideas at the moment. What would be the best way to troubleshoot this?

The error message I get is ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

These are the rules in the firewall. They look exactly the same for old and new server, except for ip adresses of course.

NAT Port forward:

```
If  Proto   Src. addr   Src. ports  Dest. addr  Dest. ports NAT IP  NAT Ports           
WAN TCP     *           *           extip       80 (HTTP)   intip   80 (HTTP)
```

NAT Outbound:

```
Interface   Source  Source Port Destination Destination Port    NAT Address NAT Port    Static Port
WAN         intip   *           *           *                   extip       *           NO
```

WAN Rules:

```
ID  Proto     Source    Port    Destination Port        Gateway Queue   Schedule
    IPv4 TCP  *         *       intip       80 (HTTP)   *       none
```

Virtual IP

```
Virtual IP address  Interface   Type
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/29  WAN         ip alias
```

Comment: When you give the new server the old IP does it work? If not it might be more a host-header/virtual-Server-config problem. If it does work then you are missing rules (most likely NAT rewrites) for the new IP (on any of the devices in between. I assume you checked how many IPs and routing entries the old server has.

Comment: If you need more help provide a network diagram with all components, addresses, routes and rules.

Comment: @eckes Yes, it does work via the internal. I've added more info now.

Comment: The question is if it works externally as well. This way you can find out if it is the web config or the network config.

Comment: The details you added on which machine are they and are they for the new or old server?

Comment: Oh, you mean if I give the new server the IP of the server it will replace? I cannot try that unfortunately. It would be a good solution, but this needs to work before I do such a thing. The old server is still in production.

Comment: Ok, can't help you much here, but a connection refused (if you get it while connecting the main URL not any redirection) means it is a problem very early (the NAT Firewall or before). Maybe hit counters of those rules help you to find out. Good luck.

Comment: @eckes I posted the wrong error message. It was a timeout, not a refuse.